# How can I get the mark-up for "add new item" link inside my list view, that opens inside a dialog box

Tags: sharepoint-designer, development, css, page-layout, html

I have the following list view:-

[image]

But I need to add the “+ Add new item” link inside another page. So can anyone advice how I can get the mark-up for add new item which will display the form inside a dialog box. I tried adding this inside a code snippet:-

```
<a target="_self" onclick="NewItem2(event, &quot;http://tvstg01/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=8&amp;ListId=%7B9F1C7DA9%2D2238%2D43E5%2D8AA0%2D9A83A1792130%7D&amp;RootFolder=&quot;); return false;" data-viewctr="1" href="amp;ListId=%7B9F1C7DA9%2D2238%2D43E5%2D8AA0%2D9A83A1792130%7D&amp;RootFolder=" id="idHomePageNewItem" class="ms-addnew">Add new item</a>
```

But the new form will not be shown inside a dialog, although inside the list settings I mentioned to show edit form inside a dialog:-

[image]

Of course i original link will show new form inside a dialog box, but if i copy the related markup inside a code snippet the form will not be shown inside a dialog ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using the below script in CEWP:

```
<a onclick="modalcall()" href="#">Add New Item</a><script type="text/javascript">
function modalcall() {
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({
        url: "NewForm.aspx",
        title: "New Item",
        //allowMaximize: true, 
        //showClose: true, 
        dialogReturnValueCallback: refreshCallback
    });
};
function refreshCallback(dialogResult, returnValue) {
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
}
```